# Code for Canvas drawing mode

Tags: javascript, canvas

Im trying to make a small drawing tool with Canvas.Today Im working on rectangle. This is my code :

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <form name="Show">
            X <input type="text" name="MouseX" value="0" size="4"><br>
            Y <input type="text" name="MouseY" value="0" size="4"><br>
       </form>
       <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
          Your browser does not support Canvas !!
       </canvas>
        <div>
        <select name="color">
        <option value="black" selected>Black</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="brown">Brown</option>
        </select>
        <img id="rectMode" src="rectMode.png" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="clear">Clear the draw</button>
        </div>
    </div>


<script language="JavaScript">

var color= 'black';
var mode= 0;
/**
 * All functions here
 */
function draw(startX, startY, endX, endY)   {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
    ctx.strokeStyle= color;
    ctx.stroke();
}
function drawRect(startX, startY, width, height)   {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(startX, startY, width, height);
    ctx.strokeStyle= color;
    ctx.stroke();
}
/**
 * Change draw color
 */
$("select[name=color]").change(function(){
    color= $(this).val();
})

/**
 * Draw Mode
 * 0: normal
 * 1: draw Rectangle
 */
$("#rectMode").click(function(){
    if(mode!= 1) {
        mode= 1;
        $(this).attr('src','rectMode1.png');
    }
    else  {
        mode= 0;
        $(this).attr('src','rectMode.png');
    }
})

/**
 * Get Cursor Coordinates
 */
ctx= $("#canvas")[0].getContext('2d');

var IE = document.all?true:false;
if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;
var tempX = 0;
var tempY = 0;
var pos= new Array();

function getMouseXY(e) {
if (IE) {
    tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
    tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
}
else {  
    tempX = e.pageX;
    tempY = e.pageY;
    tempX -= $("#canvas").offset().left;
    tempY -= $("#canvas").offset().top;
}  
if (tempX < 0) {
    tempX = 0;
}
if (tempY < 0) {
    tempY = 0;
}  
document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX;
document.Show.MouseY.value = tempY;

pos[0]= tempX;
pos[1]= tempY;
return true;
}

/**
 * On mouse down get cursor coordinates to start drawing
 */
$("#canvas").mousedown(function(){
    getMouseXY;
    startY= pos[1];
    // On mouse move keep drawing with mode
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(){
        getMouseXY;
        endX= pos[0];
        endY= pos[1];
        if(mode==1) {
            width= endX - startX;
            height= endY- startY;
            ctx.clearRect(startX, startY, width, height);
            drawRect(startX, startY, width, height);
        }
        else  {
            draw(startX, startY, endX, endY);
            startX= pos[0];
            startY= pos[1];
        }
    })
})

/**
 *  On mouse up stop drawing
 */
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    $("canvas").unbind("mousemove");
})

/**
 * Clear Canvas Content
 */
$("#clear").click(function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
})
</script>
</body>
```

Well, my problem is: 
Exp: When I mousedown at coordinate (10,10) and mousemove to (100,100), a rectangle is draw correctly. But when I continue mousemove back to (90,90),all rectangle from (100,100) to (90,90) is not clear as I expected.

This always happens when I move the mouse to somewhere than move it back close to start point.

Can someone have a look at my code and tell me what is wrong,I cleared the previous rectangle before draw new one,so this error supposed not to happen.

Pls help me out,tks you so much :)

Comment: Your `mouseup` handler calls unbind on `canvas` and not `#canvas` like the rest of you code. Also don't use `<script language="javascript">`, do `<script type="text/javascript">` (although that's not the cause of your current problem)

Comment: I fixed that but it's not the problem cause my <canvas> has id="canvas" so it still work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of the coordinates of the previous draw operation. As it is, you are just clearing the area that you are about to draw for every frame, which means that as the rectangle shrinks you are not clearing the area previously drawn, only part of it.

In order to ascertain this I have refactored your code quite heavily in places, so please ask if there is anything I have done that you do not understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/DaveRandom/YUtpH/1/

```
var color = 'black',
    rectMode = 0,
    IE = document.all ? true : false,
    $canvas = $("#canvas"),
    ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');

/**
 * All functions here
 */
function getMouseXY(e, $canvas) {
    var pos = {};

    if (IE) {
        pos.x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
        pos.y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    } else {
        pos.x = e.pageX - $canvas.offset().left;
        pos.y = e.pageY - $canvas.offset().top;
    }

    document.Show.MouseX.value = pos.x = Math.min(300, Math.max(0, pos.x));
    document.Show.MouseY.value = pos.y = Math.min(300, Math.max(0, pos.y));

    return pos;
}

function draw(action, startPos, endPos) {
    action.ctx.beginPath();
    if (action.rectMode) {
        drawRect(action);
    } else {
        drawLine(action);
    }
    action.ctx.strokeStyle = action.color;
    action.ctx.stroke();
}

function drawLine(action) {
    action.ctx.moveTo(action.start.x, action.start.y);
    action.ctx.lineTo(action.end.x, action.end.y);
    action.start = action.end;
}

function drawRect(action) {
    var clearX = action.last.x + (action.last.w < 0 ? 1 : -1),
        clearY = action.last.y + (action.last.h < 0 ? 1 : -1),
        clearW = action.last.w + (action.last.w < 0 ? -2 : 2),
        clearH = action.last.h + (action.last.h < 0 ? -2 : 2),
        drawX = action.start.x,
        drawY = action.start.y,
        drawW = action.end.x - action.start.x,
        drawH = action.end.y - action.start.y;

    action.ctx.clearRect(clearX, clearY, clearW, clearH);
    action.ctx.rect(drawX, drawY, drawW, drawH);

    action.last = {
        x: drawX,
        y: drawY,
        w: drawW,
        h: drawH
    };
}

/**
 * Get Cursor Coordinates
 */
if (!IE) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
}

/**
 * Change draw color
 */
$("select[name=color]").change(function(){
    color = $(this).val();
});

/**
 * Draw Mode
 * 0: normal
 * 1: draw Rectangle
 */
$("#rectMode").click(function() {
    if (rectMode) {
        rectMode = 0;
        $(this).attr('src','rectMode.png');
    } else {
        rectMode = 1;
        $(this).attr('src','rectMode1.png');
    }
});

/**
 * On mouse down get cursor coordinates to start drawing
 */
$canvas.mousedown(function(e) {
    var startPos = getMouseXY(e, $canvas),
        action = {
            ctx: ctx,
            color: color,
            rectMode: rectMode,
            start: startPos,
            last: {
                x: startPos.x,
                y: startPos.y,
                w: 0,
                y: 0
            }
        };

    // On mouse move keep drawing with mode
    $canvas.mousemove(function(e){
        action.end = getMouseXY(e, $canvas);
        draw(action);
    });
});

/**
 * On mouse up stop drawing
 */
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    $canvas.unbind("mousemove");
});

/**
 * Clear Canvas Content
 */
$("#clear").click(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
});
```